# How to return parameters from all iterations of spicy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, scipy, minimization

I am using `scipy.optimize.fmin` to optimize the Rosenbrock function:

```
import scipy
import bumpy as np
def rosen(x):
    """The Rosenbrock function"""
    return sum(100.0*(x[1:]-x[:-1]**2.0)**2.0 + (1-x[:-1])**2.0)

x0 = np.array([1.3, 0.7, 0.8, 1.9, 1.2])
scipy.optimize.fmin(rosen, x0, full_output=True)
```

this returns a tuple for the solution (parameter that minimizes the function, the function minimum, number of iterations, number of function calls).

However I would like to be able to graph the values at each step. For example I would to plot the iteration number along the x-axis and the running minimum value along the y-axis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fmin can take an optional callback function that gets called at each step, so you can just create a simple one that grabs the values at each step:

```
def save_step(k):
    global steps
    steps.append(k)

steps = []
scipy.optimize.fmin(rosen, x0, full_output=True, callback=save_step)
print np.array(steps)[:10]
```

Output:

```
[[ 1.339       0.721       0.824       1.71        1.236     ]
 [ 1.339       0.721       0.824       1.71        1.236     ]
 [ 1.339       0.721       0.824       1.71        1.236     ]
 [ 1.339       0.721       0.824       1.71        1.236     ]
 [ 1.2877696   0.7417984   0.8013696   1.587184    1.3580544 ]
 [ 1.28043136  0.76687744  0.88219136  1.3994944   1.29688704]
 [ 1.28043136  0.76687744  0.88219136  1.3994944   1.29688704]
 [ 1.28043136  0.76687744  0.88219136  1.3994944   1.29688704]
 [ 1.35935594  0.83266045  0.8240753   1.02414244  1.38852256]
 [ 1.30094767  0.80530982  0.85898166  1.0331386   1.45104273]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Randy for the answer.

Because some optimization methods emits more arguments when call callback (for example: 'trust-constr'), I found this solution more effective:

```
import numpy

steps = []


def save_step(*args):
    for arg in args:
        if type(arg) is numpy.ndarray:
            steps.append(arg)
```

And example of usage is:

```
def f(x):
    x1 = x[0]
    x2 = x[1]
    return -(-4 * x1 * x1 - 4 * x2 * x2 + 4 * x1 * x2 + 8 * x1 + 20 * x2)


def gradient(x):
    x1 = x[0]
    x2 = x[1]
    return np.array([
        -(-8 * x1 + 4 * x2 + 8),
        -(-8 * x2 + 4 * x1 + 20)
    ])

start_point = np.zeros(2)

result = minimize(
    fun=f,
    x0=start_point,
    method='trust-constr',
    jac=gradient,
    callback=save_step
)
print(result)
print(steps)
```